# Take parentheses as an object while splitting arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a program to split arguments in a string in Node.js, and I'm using .split(" "). Here's an example:
`"arg1 arg2 (arg3,arg4)"`

This returns:
`["arg1", "arg2", "(arg3,arg4)"]`
works as intended

But what I also want to do is take items in parentheses as 1 single object. For example:
`"arg1 arg2 (arg3, arg_after_space)"`

Returns `["arg1", "arg2", "(arg3,", "arg_after_space)"]` if using .split(" ")

What I want `["arg", "arg2", "(arg3, arg_after_space)"]`

I want this to work with "", {}, (), [], and basically every symbol that is used as a pair in Node.js, but how can I do that?

I tried .split(" ") but just cannot figure out how to do that

Comment: You’re basically inventing your own mini language, so will need your own mini parser. Is this really where you want to go? Isn’t there an easier way to express your data?

Comment: You have to include `"arg1 arg2 (arg3,arg_after_space)"`, because all you're separating are spaces